# How to increase size of user interface of browser in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: resize, text

I want to **increase** the size of text along with links and tabs in my browser of Ubuntu 20.04 . I want it to be as in **Windows** Browser. Here it is very difficult to see without stretching my eyes.

Comment: What is "Windows browser"?

Comment: What browser Ubuntu can run many please be clear.

Comment: Have you tried `"Ctrl"` + `"+"` when on the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

The default browser in Ubuntu is Firefox. To zoom in, i.e., increase the size of the display of a web page, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. To zoom out, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. To reset the zoom level, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. The zoom level is remembered per site.

If you want to change the default zoom level, i.e. such that each page initially is displayed at a larger size, then change "Zoom" in Settings to a higher number (default: 100%).